# Compile error when calling a move overloaded function with an implicitly convertible object

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, clang, move-semantics

This program does not compile using `clang++ test.cpp -std=c++0x`:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    A(const A&) {}
    A(A&&) {}
    A& operator = (const A&) { return *this; }
    A& operator = (A&&) { return *this; }
};

class B
{
    A m_a;
public:
    operator const A &() const
    {
        return m_a;
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a = b; // compile error
}
```

Compile errors:

```
Apple clang version 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.10.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)

test.cpp:25:9: error: no viable conversion from 'B' to 'A'
    a = b;
        ^
test.cpp:5:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'B' to
      'const A &' for 1st argument
    A(const A&) {}
    ^
test.cpp:6:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'B' to 'A &&'
      for 1st argument
    A(A&&) {}
    ^
test.cpp:15:5: note: candidate function
    operator const A &() const
    ^
test.cpp:8:23: note: passing argument to parameter here
    A& operator = (A&&) { return *this; }
                      ^
```

Why does it not compile? Why does the compiler prefer `A::operator = (A&&)` over `A::operator = (const A&)`?

In addition, why would `A a = b;` compile while both `A a; a = b;` (the above program) and `A a(b);` do not?

Comment: FWIW, your code compiles as-is with `clang version 3.0 (tags/RELEASE_30/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix` and GCC 4.5.3 or 4.6.2 (but I have no idea if that is normal or not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what bug this is, but the version of Clang you are testing is fairly old, especially with respect to C++11 features. You probably want to use at the very least the [3.0 release of Clang](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.0), which correctly accepts this AFAIK. I tested it with a recent revision of the Clang SVN trunk, and it worked fine.

Given that Clang's C++11 support is still under very active development, don't be surprised if there are also bugs in the 3.0 release. You may have more success with a build directly from the SVN trunk. There are instructions [here](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) for checking out the code from subversion and building a fresh set of Clang binaries.